# Understanding pattern matching with sample code

Tags: scala

Below is code that I'm trying to use to illustrate pattern matching :

```
package patternmatching

object patterntest {

    abstract class Expr
    case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
    case class Number(num: Double) extends Expr
    case class UnOp(operator: String , arg: Expr) extends Expr
    case class BinOp(operator: String, left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr

    def simplifyTop(expr: Expr): Expr = expr match {
      case UnOp("-", UnOp("-", e)) => e //double negation
      case BinOp("+", e, Number(0)) => e  //adding zero
      case BinOp("*", e, Number(1)) => e //Mutiplying by one
      case _ => expr
    }


   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      UnOp("-" , UnOp("-", e))
    }

}
```

How can I test each of the patterns ? The line UnOp("-" , UnOp("-", e))
 within the main method gives an error :

```
not found: value e
```

Comment: `UnOp("-" , UnOp("-", Var("foo")))` in main, no?

Comment: @om-nom-nom thanks, would you mind explaining how pattern matching works in above context. I still dont understand it.

Comment: In the main method you are constructing two nested UnOp where the inner one the second argument you try to pass an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace the main method with the following one:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sample = UnOp("-" , UnOp("-", Number(0)) // no more undefined variable
  val simplified = simplifyTop(sample)
  println(simplified)
}
```

It will probably print something like `Number(0)` which is a match to the first case expression.

Personally, I like to think that cases classes constructs values and pattern match *deconstructs* them. In this process of *deconstructing* values with patter match you can also bind the pieces to variables. After a match has occurred you use these variables.

For example, in `simplifyTop` the `BinOp("+", e, Number(0))` will match when `expr` is a BinOp, its `operator` field has value "+" and `right` field has value "Number(0)", the `left` field can have any instance of `Expr` and its value will be bound to the variable `e`.

Another example would be `case BinOp("+", Number(l), Number(r)) => Number(l+r)`, this case would not only extract - the *deconstruction* in Scala jargon - the outer value of type BinOp but also its inner parts, which are `Number`s.